# Umbraco Querying from Macro Script?

Tags: razor, umbraco

Umbraco Version = 6.0.3

I'm trying to do some seemingly simple stuff in a macro scriptlet. Basically, I want to loop through all of the visible child content that is not a category:

```
@inherits umbraco.MacroEngines.DynamicNodeContext

@{
var subs = Model.Children.Where("Visible && DocumentTypeAlias != \"Category\"");
}
<span>Count: @subs.Count()</span>
@if (subs.Any())
{
    <ul>            
        @foreach (var sub in subs)
        {
            <li>
                <a href="@sub.Url">@sub.Name</a>
            </li>
        }
    </ul>
}
```

If I take out the "Visible" portion of the where clause, it works correctly (with the exception of displaying content marked as hidden). I can also use "Visible" on it's own by removing the "DocumentTypeAlias", but then all visible content including categories are displayed.

I also tried using strongly typed queries `@Model.Content.Children.Where(x => x.IsVisible() && x.DocumentTypeAlias != "Category")` but I get an error about not being able to use lambda functions with dynamically typed content.

Ideas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Two things:

- The `DynamicNode` `Where` clause uses a parameter syntax.
- Use `NodeTypeAlias` to check the document type.

Example:

```
var subs = Model.Children.Where("Visible && NodeTypeAlias != @0", "Category");
```

Here are a few Umbraco razor resources:

- [Umbraco 4.7 Razor Feature Walkthrough](http://umbraco.com/follow-us/blog-archive/2011/2/23/umbraco-47-razor-feature-walkthrough-%E2%80%93-part-1.aspx). It's a 8-part series and it's pretty informative. Don't be put off by the version reference, it's still valid for Umbraco 6.
- [Razor DynamicNode Cheat Sheet](http://our.umbraco.org/projects/developer-tools/razor-dynamicnode-cheat-sheet).

Comment: Also just found using CurrentModel vs Model within the scripting file makes it strongly typed so that I can do lambdas